# Adding value to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to add a value to a key in HTML5 localStorage.

Here is my code:

```
    var splice_string = [];
    splice_string += "Test value";
    var original = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product_1'));
    original['spliced'] = JSON.stringify(splice_string);
```

This doesn't seem to work because when I check the localStorage the `original['spliced']` is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: splice_string is empty

Comment: No, I didn't paste in the whole function...sorry updating the Q now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```
var splice_string = 'Test Value',
    original = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product_1'));

// you might want to add checking for existence here, with something like...
// if (original === null) original = {};

original['spliced'] = splice_string;
localStorage.setItem('product_1', JSON.stringify(original));
```

In the code you've shown not only `splice_string` contains something that's not a string, but you don't actually store the updated value of `original` in `localStorage`.